# byte string as Data in Swift 4

Tags: swift, string, audio, types, byte

I have a string that looks like this:

`ID3\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00#TSSE\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x03Lavf57.71.100\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xf3\xc4\x00\x1a\xa2\x95\xf8\x15X\x10\x00\x16\xa0V\x18\xbb\x18\x84\x99i\x96|\xc60P\xdc\xe5\x03\xf1\xe6p\xe2Y}\xdc\xb8\xbe=\xfd\xe7OOo:\x10\x84S\x9es\xd0\x84#|\xe79\xce\xdf\xf4!\x1aw\xa9\xces\xd1\xa4$\xe79\xdf\xc8\xdf\xces\xfc\x84!\t\x90\x8d\xa9\xe8s\xd0\x8d\xff\xffS ...`

How can I convert this into Data in swift?

I have tried using `str as! Data` but that just throws an error

The string is coming as one of the return values to a post request to a server of mine

**Code**

```
Alamofire.request(serverURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            let responseData = (response.result.value! as! [String: Any])
            var audio = responseData["audio"]!
}
```

Comment: Why do you have data as a string? Where is it coming from? Show some relevant code in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy I have just updated my question

Comment: Do you mean that the original JSON response looks like `{"audio":"ID3\\x04\\x00...",...}` ?

Answer (score 1):

The Alamofire [docs](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-handling) say response.result should be serialized JSON. Do you mean to access the data via response.data?

```
if let json = response.result.value {
    print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
}

if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
}
```

Comment: The goal is not to get a string but to get data from a specific field in the response.

Answer (score 0):

The string you are providing is [MP3 metadata](https://phoxis.org/2010/05/08/what-are-id3-tags-all-about/) and I'm guessing part of a larger MP3 file. Assuming you are unable to retrieve by [downloading the file directly to your machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48485812/1694526) or using a remote URL, then you can convert the text string to data in the following way:

```
let data = str.data(using: .utf8)
```

Note: This returns an optional, so you need to handle that.